# Current source in parallel with a short circuit

Tags: current, current-source, passive-networks, phasor, norton

If a **Dependent** current source is placed in parallel with a short circuit,
to solve our calculations would we assume that no current will flow through the dependent source and hence we remove it. For example in the picture to form a norton equivalent circuit across a-b i placed a short circuit to find In(current in the short circuit).
[image]

Comment: Find a Thevenin equivalent of the current source with the short, and you will see.

Comment: Current will flow through the source. But all of it will flow through the short circuit, so it won't affect anything.